# How to sign a PDF document using digital signature page wise?

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I'm trying to sign a document page wise digitally.Is it logically correct ?
Currently the signature is coming in one page only,Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);

FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);

PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');

// Creating the appearance

PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();

appearance.setLocation(location);
        appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);

appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(44, 170, 144, 221), 1, "sig");

appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(44, 170, 144, 221), 7, "sig");

// Creating the signature

ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);

ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, crlList,ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize,subfilter);
```

Comment: Check out the `sign()` method here in iText example: https://github.com/itext/i7js-samples/blob/develop/publications/signatures/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter02/C2_01_SignHelloWorld.java

Comment: An integrated PDF signature always covers the whole document revision but is meant to have but one visualization. There are some techniques to add multiple visualizations for a single signature, some are violating the PDF specification outright, some merely its spirit.